# CALayer memory management

Tags: ios, xcode

I have discovered that CALayer uses up a lot of memory. Since i have many images, removing the layer, I have seen it is very fast:

```
CALayer * l = [image1 layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:6.0];
```

Can I do this instead:

```
image1.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
                image1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Will it take up less memory?? Is there another way??

Answer (score 0):

No it won't take up less memory. Storing a reference in a variable to an object doesn't copy the object - the two approaches are equivalent and both of them are correct.

Comment: Any way to take up less memory??